# Canvas drawBitmap with Matrix, the scale pixel point have sawtooth

Tags: android, android-canvas, android-bitmap

I want to draw scale-bitmap on canvas by matrix, but some scaled pixel point have sawtooth, i try to use `paint.setAntiAlias(true)`, but it not work, how to fix it, thanks your help.

This is my code

```
 mMatrix.setScale(mScale, mScale);
 mMatrix.postTranslate(mPaintStartPoint.x, mPaintStartPoint.y);
 canvas.drawBitmap(mCacheMap, mMatrix, mBgPaint);
```

Original bitmap:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Un38.png)

And the scale bitmap in canvas:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iWY5E.png)

Comment: what does the original bitmap look like?

Comment: @pskink This bitmap is created by myself, use `bitmap.setPixel` method to tint pixel point, Not only the bitmap have this problem, as you see, every color box is apixel point, but some pixel point have sawtooth, if user `mMatrix.postTranslate` to another (x,y), some time the sawtooth is gone.

Comment: i have no idea what you mean

Comment: @pskink Sorry about my english, I'm try again. you know bitmap save every pixel-point's color, if you enlarge bitmap, you can see every pixel-point like my screenshot, but some pixel-point have sawtooth.

Comment: what does the original bitmap look like? what are values of `mScale` and `mPaintStartPoint`?

Comment: @pskink I add original bitmap to question, `mScale` and `mPaintStartPoint` are dynamic, `mScale` > 1

Comment: you have those "sawtooth" on the original bitmap too

Comment: @pskink I update my question, the original bitmap [link](http://i.stack.imgur.com/0Un38.png), and the screenshot [link](http://i.stack.imgur.com/iWY5E.png)

Comment: how do you load the original bitmap? is it under res/drawable-* folder? if so, where?

Comment: @pskink i create a new bitmap, and use `bitmap.setPixel` to tint, the original bitmap is export by `FileOutputStream`.

Comment: so read the bitmap directly via `BitmapFactory` (do not use any indirect bitmaps) and compare the results

Comment: @pskink some values of `mScale` and `mPaintStartPoint` will make the scale bitmap have "sawtooth", but the scale bitmap with another values show normal.